# Network error in use of axios and fetch in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I want to use axios in my app project but get this error

> network request failed

my code is:

```
  fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json').then(function(response) {

      alert(response.data);
  }).catch(function(response) {

      alert(response)

  });
```

and I tested this but it does not work too

axios:

```
   Axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json').then(function(response) {

   }).catch(function(error) {
       // alert(error)
       console.warn(error)
   });
```

Comment: Do you get this error on ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you.

```
state = { abc:[] };

componentWillMount() {

 axios.get('url')//lowercase a
.then(response => this.setState({abc:response.data})).catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
 });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why? I'm having the same problem and this doesn't help me at all.